# Coroutine called by event that requires another coroutine to finish

Tags: kotlin, coroutine

In my `ViewModel` I have a function that is called from UI. It can be called many times per second.

Data comes from barcode scanner ViewModel. I'm passing it from one ViewModel to another thru UI for simplicity and to reuse barcode scanner ViewModel.

For simplicity lets assume that I have something like this:

```
// called from the fragment (that observes some property on the another viewmodel)
public fun processScannedBarcode(barcode : String){
    // process data after necessaryData is ready (not null?)
    val item = findItemByBarcode(barcode)
}

private var dataFromApi: ArrayList<Item>?

private fun loadNecessaryDataFromTheApi(){
    viewModelScope.launch {
        canReload = false
        dataFromApi = myapi.getDataFromApi() // suspend fun inside
        canReload = true
    }
}

// called from the fragment button click
public fun reloadNecessaryDataFromTheApi(){
    loadNecessaryDataFromTheApi()
}

init {
    loadNecessaryDataFromTheApi()
}
```

My data required to process may be not ready yet because it comes from the API. I have to deferr that processing and resume when data is ready.

I could simply solve this with some Queue and a Thread, but maybe it is possible to do that with Kotlin coroutines?

Comment: What should happen if we call to reload the necessary data? Should we defer processing barcodes again or this happens only during the initial loading?

Comment: In situation like this (if we call reloading data) we should block processing until refresh operation will finish, but I think we can skip this at this moment. I need some idea to start with and then I will try to figure out more complex application states.

Answer (score 1):

As your `loadNecessaryDataFromTheApi()` only sets properties, it is not that easy to observe it or wait for it. You need to use some synchronization utility like locks, channels, etc. In this case it will be probably the easiest to keep a `Deferred` of the necessary data:

```kotlin
public suspend fun processScannedBarcode(barcode : String){
    val data = dataFromApi.await()
    val item = findItemByBarcode(barcode)
}

private val dataFromApi = CompletableDeferred<ArrayList<Item>>()

private fun loadNecessaryDataFromTheApi(){
    viewModelScope.launch {
        canReload = false
        dataFromApi.complete(myapi.getDataFromApi())
        canReload = true
    }
}
```

Some notes:

1. We have to make `processScannedBarcode` suspend if it is going to wait for something.
2. If you want `reloadNecessaryDataFromTheApi()` to defer processing barcodes again, simply replace `dataFromApi` with a new deferred.